# Self many-to-many reference OrmLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have table with product, and I need to store related products. For that I use association table to store IDs for related products. which in simplified model looks like:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = Product.TABLE_NAME)
public class Product {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "product";

    public interface Fields extends BaseModel.Fields {
        String MODEL = "model";
        String SERIES = "series";
        String IS_NEW = "is_new";
        String IS_BESTSELLER = "is_bestseller";
        String FICHE = "fiche";
        String MANUAL = "manual";
        String URL = "web_url";
        String VIDEO_URL = "video_presentation";
        String VIDEO_360_URL = "video_360_presentation";
    }

    @DatabaseField(columnName = Fields.ID, id = true)
    private long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(columnName = Feature.TABLE_NAME)
    private ForeignCollection<ProductFeatures> features;

    @ForeignCollectionField(columnName = RelatedProducts.TABLE_NAME)
    private ForeignCollection<RelatedProducts> related;

    public Product() {
    }
}


@DatabaseTable(tableName = RelatedProducts.TABLE_NAME)
public class RelatedProducts {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "related_products";
    public interface Fields extends BaseModel.Fields {

        String PRODUCT_FK = "product_id";
        String RELATED_FK = "related_product_id";
    }

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, columnName = Fields.PRODUCT_FK
            , foreignAutoRefresh = true, maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 2, columnDefinition =
            "INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES " + Product.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Product.Fields.ID + ")")
    Product product_;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, columnName = Fields.RELATED_FK
            , foreignAutoRefresh = true, maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 2, columnDefinition =
            "INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES " + Product.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Product.Fields.ID + ")")
    Product relatedProduct;

    public RelatedProducts() {
    }
```

But when trying to add/instantiate DB, which means to create the whole logic I get an error:

```
08-14 10:43:29.014  24133-24170/XXX.XXX.xxx E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: XXX.XXX.xxx, PID: 24133
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store class XXX.XXX.xxx.model.Product for field product. Use another class or a custom persister.
            at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.<init>(FieldType.java:189)
            at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.convertFieldConfigs(DatabaseTableConfig.java:236)
            at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:101)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:153)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:72)
            at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.configDaoInformation(FieldType.java:297)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:201)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:72)
            at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:218)
            at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:61)
            at XXX.XXX.commons.util.db.OrmLiteTableUtils.createIfNotExists(OrmLiteTableUtils.java:35)
            at XXX.XXX.infrastructure.db.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:80)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onCreate(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:66)
            at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:54)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.idExists(BaseDaoImpl.java:805)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:335)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao.createOrUpdate(RuntimeExceptionDao.java:249)
            at XXX.XXX.infrastructure.db.GenericDao.persist(GenericDao.java:44)
            at XXX.XXX.xxx.server.DeviceRegistration.addUser(DeviceRegistration.java:54)
            at XXX.XXX.xxx.server.DeviceRegistration.doInBackground(DeviceRegistration.java:36)
            at XXX.XXX.xxx.server.DeviceRegistration.doInBackground(DeviceRegistration.java:20)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any ideas how to make such reference?

Comment: Are you sure that the Product in question has the same package as your `Product` entity?  Are you sure you don't have a bad `import` there?

Answer (score 0):

> IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store class XXX.XXX.xxx.model.Product for field product. Use another class or a custom persister.

About the only thing that I can guess is that there is an incorrect `Product` here.  That the `Product` field is pointing to a different `Product` class that does not have an `@DatabaseTable` annotation and so ORMLite doesn't know what to do with it.

Make sure that the `XXX.XXX.xxx.model.Product` is the correct package name.